# Yocto post-build script

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, yocto

I'm running a Yocto build environment inside an EC2 instance. As building could take a long time, I'd like to be able to run builds at night. However, when building is finished, my EC2 instance is still running and costing me money. I'm using Toaster to initiate my builds.

Is there any way to get the instance to shut down after all builds are finished?

Comment: What linux distro? Did you try calling `shutdown` at the end of post build script? Otherwise AWS CLI or SDK is a solution.

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu. I know how I'd shut down the instance from a script, but I don't know how to define a post-build script in Yocto

Comment: Why does this have to be part of the build? You presumably call bitbake from terminal -- why not call a script that calls bitbake and then shuts down the instance instead?

Comment: I should have specified that I'm using Toaster to run my builds

Comment: Better check bitbake in ps -el | grep bitbake  take the pid and using pid you can shutdown

Comment: As @jku said run bitbake manually.
Making a shutdown in a postprocess function will not finish the build.
The best way is to call bitbake && shutdown. This way you will only shutdown on successsfull bitbake. If not just replace && with ;

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can programmatically [start and stop instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Stop_Start.html#starting-stopping-instances).

You might be wanting to add a preliminar stage to launch instances, wait for them to launch, then run your builds, and then finally stop them.

You don't mention your OS but im guessing it surely is Linux, then just use the Amazon CLI to [start](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/start-instances.html) and [stop](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/stop-instances.html) your instances.

This is very convenient as you could rent a very powerful instance and just run for short bursts of time while you are building.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but the main issue wasn’t access to the AWS API, which is well known and thoroughly documented. As clarified in comments, the issue I was facing was how to get Yocto or Toaster to run a script after builds are finished. However, I’m currently not working on this project anymore, so I don’t need an answer anymore.

Comment: In that case you could just run bitbake blabla && sudo poweroff, then add the user to passwordless sudo group. It would poweroff only on success.

Comment: That's not a big help when using Toaster, which is a web-based interface to the yocto build tools

Comment: Well, your question is specific to Yocto, so bitbake is the way to go. If not you should reformulate to be more specific and as something as: "How yo use Toaster to do...". In any case bitbake is the tool behind so the answer will have to take it into consideration.

Comment: My question already states that I’m using Toaster to initiate my builds

Comment: Yes but the title is misleading, and the note is just a remark.